# filter a tiff image to reduce its pixel numbers without changing its bit depth

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a black-white tiff image with 15369x15360 pixels and 8 bit depth now I want to convert this image to a 7680x7680 tiff image and I want its bit depth to remain 8
what code can I use in matlab to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to resize the image? Do you want [`imresize()` from the Image Processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of an image should never change the bit depth. Have a look at

http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html

Comment: you are right resizing the image with **imresize** function will not effect its bit depth and the compression type will be PackBits but if you open the image with paint to do some editing on it and then save, the compression type gets LZW and bit depth gets 32   _in fact I want to solve this problem_

Comment: Don't crosspost unrelated stuff to a question where you've already accepted an answer. Instead, let your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889709/save-a-tiff-image-without-changing-its-bit-depth-and-compression-type/9889819#9889819) stand alone.